# Why isn't opAssign overloadable for classes?

Tags: operator-overloading, d, assignment-operator

[This D specification table](https://dlang.org/spec/struct.html) says that [assignment overloading](https://dlang.org/spec/struct.html#AssignOverload) is only possible for structs, not classes. This surprises me. Isn't the syntactic sugar of `A = B` harmless?  What was the design rationale for restricting it to structs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In D, classes are used by reference. So, when you do A = B, you do not copy the object itself, but just a reference to that object.

None of objects are modified during the process. So it makes no sense to define opAssign for thoses.

Answer (score 4):

D classes have reference semantics. If you want a way to get a copy of the object (it think) the standard or conventional thing to do is provide a `.dup` property.

Comment: I don't believe that there's really a standard at this point, but `.dup` would be a common way to do it, and if we _do_ decide on an actual standard, then that would be the likely choice.

Comment: Which uses the postblit, which you can define by this(this) {} in your class. It is post-blit, so all variables have been copied, you just need to do work on the pointer variables in the class. By dup'ing them for instance.

Comment: @JonathanMDavis: Standard as in normal, not standard as in ISO. :o)

Comment: @BCS I meant standard as in even generally agreed upon that that's the way to do it. I don't think that it's even necessarily something that the majority of D users do. It's common enough, and if a general agreement _were_ to be reached, then there's a good chance that that would be it, but AFAIK there is not currently such a general agreement.

Comment: @Daevius Classes don't have postplit constructors. They're for structs, not classes. There is no built-in way to copy the contents of a class. You have to create a function which returns a copy or create a copy-constructor - which isn't treated special like it would be in C++; it's just a constructor which takes the same type of class as the one being constructed. Typically, such a function would be named `dup` or `clone`, but only arrays have a built-in `dup` property. Any other type would have to have a user-defined one.

Comment: So a copy-constructor would look like: class A { this(A a) {} } ? It does make a clear distinction between assignment and construction syntax wise. Sorry for the misinformation!

Comment: @Daevius All the assignment that you get with classes in D is assigning references. The only copying that occurs when assigning classes is the copying of the reference. So, assignment and construction aren't related beyond the fact that you're likely to assign a newly constructed class object to a class reference. Copy constructors aren't even really copy constructors in the C++ sense. They're just constructors that happen to take the same type that they're constructing.

Comment: `A a = new A(); a = new A(a);` or `A a = new A(); a = a.dup;` (if the type supports it).

Answer (score 0):

I would file a bug, [and did](https://issues.dlang.org/show_bug.cgi?id=7075). The general rule is to follow [*The D Programming Language*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321635361) by Andrei Alexandrescu, the DMD implementation, and then the website. As I don't have a copy of *The D Programming Language* handy, I'm going with the DMD implementation on this:

```
class A {
    int a;
    string b;
    float c;
    
    void opAssign(B b) {
       a = b.a;
    }
}

class B {
    int a;
}
void main()
{
    auto a = new A();
    a.a = 5;
    auto b = new B();
    b.a = 10;
    a = b;

    assert(a.a == 10);
}
```